# Generic Icollection Of <T>

Tags: vb.net, icollection

I want to Create Object of `Icollection` of `<t>`.
My Code is as below.

```
    Dim oAttributeValues As ICollection(Of AttributeValue)
        = TryCast(AttributeValuePropertyInfo.GetValue(UOMEn, Nothing),
                  ICollection(Of AttributeValue))
```

Here `AttributeValue` is my class name. I want this Class generalized Bca I don't know which class of Collection created.

Comment: You're question doesn't completely make sense. Does that `AttributeValuePropertyInfo.GetValue` method already exist or are you trying to implement it? If it already exists then are you or are you not already getting an object returned by it? If you are, does that object implement `ICollection(Of T)`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney u r right. actually i misunderstood Icollection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class Collection(Of T As Class)
    Implements ICollection(Of T)
    Implements ICollection
    'Your code
End Class
```

Please note that you will have to implement `ICollection(Of T)` and `ICollection` interface by yourself. In case you don't want it then you might want to Inherit from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)`.

```
Public Class Collection(Of T As Class)
    Inherits  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)    
    'Your code
End Class
```